# Openshifts nodejs gear cannot connect to mongodb gear in scaled application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

Im using OpenShift as a platform for a webservice. I hoped that openshift would manage my nodejs and mongodb database for me, making sure it keeps working. However in a very short time i have encountered quite alot problems.

My latest issue is that my nodejs app suddenly cant connect to the mongodb gear anymore. 
I use MongooseJS to connect to the mongodb gear with the following code:
    var mongoConnection = '127.0.0.1:27017/movin_maps';

```
// if OPENSHIFT env variables are present, use the available connection info:
if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD){
    mongoConnection = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ':' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + '/' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
}

this.mongoose.connect(mongoConnection);
var database = this.mongoose.connection;



database.on('error', function(error){
    var date = new Date();
    console.error(date.toUTCString() + " Connection error: " + error);
});

database.on('disconnected', function(param){
    var date = new Date();
    console.error(date.toUTCString() + " Connection disconnected: " + param);
});
```

This Always used to work just fine for me, i could connect to the database and i did not have problems for about a week. But suddenly the application stops responding, and its giving the following errors:

```
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
Fri, 21 Mar 2014 09:12:29 GMT Connection disconnected: undefined
Fri, 21 Mar 2014 09:12:29 GMT Connection error: Error: failed to connect to [52b169ec5973ca78d100026b-movinsoftware.rhcloud.com:40756]
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 0
```

This is a major issue for me, because as we speak my server application is not working. I hope someone knows a decent fix, but my experiences with openshift are not really good. The promise of an easy to maintain server application fails to fulfull for me.

Sincerely,

Hylke Bron

Comment: Looks like this is caused by the bug reported here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1071473 If someone has experience with this issue and knows how to fix this, please help me on this.